# Installing Xdebug for PHP CLI

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I'm using [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/tr/index.html) on Mac OS, trying to use [PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de)'s code coverage checks, which require [XDebug](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/code-coverage-analysis.html). The xdebug.so file comes with XAMPP so I've enabled Xdebug for PHP:

```
// /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

Now, when I check from the web server, there is an Xdebug section inside the output from `phpinfo()`.

But when I'm trying to check code coverage I get an error:

```
$ phpunit --coverage-html report
PHPUnit 3.7.31 by Sebastian Bergmann.

The Xdebug extension is not loaded. No code coverage will be generated.
```

I think CLI using different `php.ini` than Apache . To find which `php.ini` file CLI is using I did this:

```
$ php -i | grep "php.ini"
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
```

But there is no `/etc/php.ini` so I copied one over:

```
$ sudo cp /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini /etc/php.ini
```

Now I'm checking `php -m` for modules, but there is no Xdebug and I'm getting this error:

```
$ php -m
Failed loading /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so, 9): Symbol not found: _zend_execute_ex
  Referenced from: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
...
```

Here is the content of [my `php.ini` file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6944846/) (check last lines.)

Can you tell me how I can enable Xdebug for PHPUnit and CLI ?

Comment: Strange, the last error looks like a binary incompatibility though.

Comment: Temporary solution : I've renamed /usr/bin/php to /usr/bin/phpp and then `ln -s /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php /usr/bin/php`

Comment: I never understood why people use those xampp packages. I saw so many problems with the setup that I doubt very much that xampp really makes things easier. It might appear like a good thing to have a single package offering all you need for basic web development. But it shows again and again that using the packages provided by the normal distribution resources cause less problems since they are better integrated into the systems. That said I have to point out that these benefits are not available for MS-Windows or MaxOSX users, since there is no such elegant concept for these systems.

Comment: Your temporary solution isn't really temporary, its the correct answer (+1). Your `php` command was using the built-in Mac OS X binary, which had a different build than what your xamp binary required. For people with similar issues run `which php` to ensure you're executing the expected binary on the command line.

Comment: Your temporary solution is dangerous and will be undone at next OS upgrade. The answer below should be accepted, and you should always leave system files (including `/etc/php.ini` alone!)

Answer (score 1):

What `which php` output you have?

Looks like you're using system-wide php instead of XAMPP version. To use XAMPP add `PATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/:PATH` to your `~/.bashrc`.