# Using PHP xdebug with the PHP CLI binary from MAMP

Tags: php, xdebug

I am using the PHP CLI binary of MAMP (ie. /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/bin/php) to execute scripts from the Terminal. How can I use Xdebug to step thru a script that I execute this way?

So far I have read:
https://joshbuchea.com/mac-enable-xdebug-in-mamp/
[Getting Xdebug Working with MAMP and Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192309/getting-xdebug-working-with-mamp-and-mac)
which mentions how to enable xdebug but only through calling the script from a web server.

And this:
[Installing Xdebug for PHP CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815982/installing-xdebug-for-php-cli)
Which is on Xdebug with XAMPP which I unfortunately find difficult to extrapolate to MAMP.

Is there not a simple way like:

```
$ phpdebugger phpfile.php
```

(
Instead of

```
$ php phpfile.php
```

)

Which will just start the debugging session with the file?

If xdebug is not suitable for this, is there another program to do this?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can either set `-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes`:

   ```
   php -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes you-script.php
   ```
2. Or, set `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` in `php.ini` (use `php --ini` to find out which file that is).
3. Or, you can use the trigger environment variable:

   ```
   XDEBUG_TRIGGER=yes php your-script.php
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I do not use MAMP but what I use to debug PHP CLI is

```
export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=your.servername.com"
php -dxdebug.client_host=xx.xx.xx.xx -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.start_with_request=yes php_command_here
```

and obviously, add breakpoints to your code.